# What do the < (smaller than) and > (bigger than) signs mean in this limit equation?

Tags: limits

I was solving problems from a textbook, and while all the other problems use the normal notation ($\lim_{x\to{a}}$), this one has the $<$ (smaller than) and $>$ (bigger than) signs under the ($\lim_{x\to{a}}$) notation.

See equation here:

[image: Equation]

Comment: I would guess [side limits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit)

Comment: Indeed, you are asked to solve $$\lim_{x\to2,x>2}$$ and to solve $$\lim_{x\to2,x<2}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Did As a matter of notation, these are often written $$\lim_{x\to 2^+} $$ and  $$\lim_{x\to 2^-} $$